# Find the invariant factors and elementary divisor form for the abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the invariant factors and elementary divisor form for the  abelian group

$ (\mathbb{Z} / {21 \mathbb{Z} )} ^* \times (\mathbb{Z} / {24 \mathbb{Z} )} ^* $

**Answer:**

The order of the above group is

$ \phi(21) \times \phi(24) =\phi(3) \times \phi(7) \times \phi(3) \times \phi(8) \ =2 \times 6 \times 2 \times 4 =2 \times 6 \times 8 $

Thus the elementary divisors are $ \ 2, 2^2, 2^3, 3 \ $

The group $ \cong \large \ \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2^2} \times (\mathbb{Z}_{2^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 ) \ $

So the invariant factors are

$ \ 2 , \ \ 2^2 , \ 2^3 \times 3 \\ i.e., \ \ 2 , \ 4 , \ \ 24 $

**How am I so far ?**

**I need confirmation.**

Comment: One of your factors is $\;\Bbb Z_{2^3}\;$, yet I can't see an element of order $\;8\;$ there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do as follows, using $\;C_n\;$ to denote the cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ :

$$C_{21}^*\cong C_2\times C_6\;,\;\;C^*_{24}\cong C_2\times C_4$$

so we get:

$$C^*_{21}\times C^*_{24}\cong C_2\times C_6\times C_2\times C_4= C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_3\times C_4$$

since $\;C_6\cong C_2\times C_3\;$ , for example. Take it from here (observe, btw, that there is no element of order $\;8\;$ here...)

Comment: If you meant the *invariant* factors then no, as there is no $\;C_8\;$ here, as shown. The factors here are $\;2,2,2,12\;$ (as far as I know, for *invariant factors* we need the divisibility condition...)

Comment: @yourmath Well, I'd rather take only the orders of the groups, but if you want the whole group then yes: that's correct.